# data from dropdownlist to db c# mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am a new comer to mvc4 c# development I am having a problem passing data to my database from a dropdownlist it keeps giving me an error that 'I must check to determine if the object is null before calling the method' I would really appreciate some help in laymans terms please as I have been trying to resolve this simple issue for two days now without success here is my code.

```
    CSHTML:
    @model UnityServiceProject.Models.NewAccountModel
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "NewAccount";
    }

    <h2>NewAccount</h2>

    @using (@Html.BeginForm()){
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true,"Please fill all required fields Thank You.")
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Create Account</legend>
        <ol>

            <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.charityName)</li>
            <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.charityName)</li>

            <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.charityNumber)</li>
            <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.charityNumber)</li>

            <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.addressLine1)</li>
            <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.addressLine1)</li>

            <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.addressLine2)</li>
            <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.addressLine2)</li>

            <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.City)</li>
            <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.City)</li>

            <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.County)</li>
            <li>@Html.DropDownList("Counties", Model.County)</li>
            <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Phone)</li>
            <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Phone)</li>
             <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Email)</li>
            <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(u =>u.Email)</li>
            <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.registeredPassword)</li>
            <li>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Comments)</li>
            <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Comments)</li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="New Account" />
    }

    MY MODEL:
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using UnityServiceProject.Models;


    namespace UnityServiceProject.Models
    {
        public class NewAccountModel
        {
            [Required]
            [StringLength(150)]
            [Display(Name="Charity Name: ")]
            public string charityName { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(150)]
            [Display(Name="Charity Number: ")]
            public string charityNumber { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100)]
            [Display(Name="Address Line 1: ")]
            public string addressLine1 { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100)]
            [Display(Name="Address Line 2: ")]
            public string addressLine2 { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100)]
            [Display(Name="City: ")]
            public string City    { get; set; }



            [Required]
            [StringLength(100)]
            [Display(Name = "Select County: ")]
            public SelectList County { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100)]
            [Display(Name="Phone Number: ")]
            public string Phone { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [StringLength(150)]//'UserLogin table field' setting max amount of characters  
            [Display(Name = "Registered Email Address: ")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [StringLength(200)]
            [Display(Name = "Registered Password: ")]
            public string registeredPassword { get; set; }



            [StringLength(300)]
            [Display(Name = "Comments: ")]
            public string Comments { get; set; }
        }
    }

    MY CONTROLLER
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Configuration;
    using UnityServiceProject.Models;


    namespace UnityServiceProject.Controllers
    {
        public class NewAccountController : Controller
        {
            //
            // GET: /NewAccount/

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult NewAccount()
            {
                return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult NewAccount(NewAccountModel newAcc)
            {
                List<SelectListItem> listItem = new List<SelectListItem>();
                NewAccountModel nam = new NewAccountModel();





             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Antrim" }
         );
             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Armagh" }
         );
             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "Carlow" }
         );
             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Cavan" }
         );
             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "5", Text = "Clare" }
         );
             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "6", Text = "Cork" }
         );
             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "7", Text = "Derry" }
         );
             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "8", Text = "Donegal" }
      );
             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "9", Text = "Down" }
      );
             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "10", Text = "Dublin" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "11", Text ="Fermanagh"}
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "12", Text = "Galway" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "13", Text = "Kerry" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "14", Text = "Kildare" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "15", Text = "Kilkenny"}
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "16", Text = "Laois" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "17", Text = "Leitrim" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "18", Text = "Limerick"}
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "19", Text "Longford"  }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "20", Text = "Louth" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "21", Text = "Mayo" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "22", Text = "Meath" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "23", Text = "Monaghan"}
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "24", Text = "Offaly" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "25", Text "Roscommon" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "26", Text = "Sligo" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "27", Text ="Tipperary"}
        );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "28", Text = "Tyrone" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Waterford"}
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text "Westmeath"  }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Wexford" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Wicklow" }
      );


         nam.County = new SelectList(listItem, "Value", "Text");

         //if (listItem != null)
         //{
         //    listItem.Clear();
         //}


           if(ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               using (var db = new UnityServiceEntities())
               {
                   //create New Account entity
                   var adNewAcc = db.AddNewAccounts.Create();

                   adNewAcc.charityName = newAcc.charityName;
                   adNewAcc.charityNumber = newAcc.charityNumber;
                   adNewAcc.addressLine1 = newAcc.addressLine1;
                   adNewAcc.addressLine2 = newAcc.addressLine2;
                   adNewAcc.City = newAcc.City;
                   adNewAcc.County = newAcc.County.SelectedValue.ToString();
                   adNewAcc.Phone = newAcc.Phone;
                   adNewAcc.emailAddress = newAcc.Email;
                   adNewAcc.registeredPassword = newAcc.registeredPassword;
                   adNewAcc.Comments = newAcc.Comments;

                   db.AddNewAccounts.Add(adNewAcc);
                   db.SaveChanges();
                   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
               }
           }
           return View(newAcc);
        }

    }
    }
Thank You!
```

Comment: Edit your question to remove all the irrelevant code. Nobody wants to wade through all this - especially hundreds of lines where you add `SelectListItem` . You question relates to one property in your model - show the code relating to that. And show the actual error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fill your dropdownlist in Get method

> You have to create  the model inside this method and set the country
>   values for dropdownlist

```
    [HttpGet]
                public ActionResult NewAccount()
                {
                    NewAccountModel accModel =new NewAccountModel();
                    List<SelectListItem> listItem = new List<SelectListItem>();
listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Antrim" }
         );
             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Armagh" }
         );
             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "Carlow" }
         );
             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Cavan" }
         );
             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "5", Text = "Clare" }
         );
             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "6", Text = "Cork" }
         );
             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "7", Text = "Derry" }
         );
             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "8", Text = "Donegal" }
      );
             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "9", Text = "Down" }
      );
             listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "10", Text = "Dublin" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "11", Text ="Fermanagh"}
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "12", Text = "Galway" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "13", Text = "Kerry" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "14", Text = "Kildare" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "15", Text = "Kilkenny"}
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "16", Text = "Laois" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "17", Text = "Leitrim" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "18", Text = "Limerick"}
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "19", Text "Longford"  }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "20", Text = "Louth" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "21", Text = "Mayo" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "22", Text = "Meath" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "23", Text = "Monaghan"}
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "24", Text = "Offaly" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "25", Text "Roscommon" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "26", Text = "Sligo" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "27", Text ="Tipperary"}
        );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "28", Text = "Tyrone" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Waterford"}
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text "Westmeath"  }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Wexford" }
      );
         listItem.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Wicklow" }
      );


         accModel.County = new SelectList(listItem, "Value", "Text");
                    return View(accModel );
                }
```

> And create a countryID in entity

And in Html you have to write dropdown like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryID, Model.Country, "Select Country", new {id = "ddlCountry"})
```

Hope this helps.